# Hijri Date Picker for Oracle ADF

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-adf, hijri

I have a project needs Hijri(Islamik) Date Picker with ADF.
I found that oracle doesn't support Hijri calendar so I'm gonna to make it with javascript.

I found an API of Hijri calendar but how can I use with ADF

```
   (function($) { // Hide scope, no $ conflict

    /* Implementation of the Islamic or '16 civil' calendar.
       Based on code from      http://www.iranchamber.com/calendar/converter/iranian_calendar_converter.php.
    See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar.
    @param  language  (string) the language code (default English) for  localisation (optional) */
    function IslamicCalendar(language) {
    this.local = this.regional[language || ''] || this.regional[''];
    }

IslamicCalendar.prototype = new $.calendars.baseCalendar;

$.extend(IslamicCalendar.prototype, {
    name: 'Islamic', // The calendar name
    jdEpoch: 1948439.5, // Julian date of start of Islamic epoch: 16 July 622 CE
    daysPerMonth: [30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 29], // Days per month in a common year
    hasYearZero: false, // True if has a year zero, false if not
    minMonth: 1, // The minimum month number
    firstMonth: 1, // The first month in the year
    minDay: 1, // The minimum day number

    regional: { // Localisations
        '': {
            name: 'Islamic', // The calendar name
            epochs: ['BH', 'AH'],
            monthNames: ['Muharram', 'Safar', 'Rabi\' al-awwal', 'Rabi\' al-thani', 'Jumada al-awwal', 'Jumada al-thani',
            'Rajab', 'Sha\'aban', 'Ramadan', 'Shawwal', 'Dhu al-Qi\'dah', 'Dhu al-Hijjah'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Muh', 'Saf', 'Rab1', 'Rab2', 'Jum1', 'Jum2', 'Raj', 'Sha\'', 'Ram', 'Shaw', 'DhuQ', 'DhuH'],
            dayNames: ['Yawm al-ahad', 'Yawm al-ithnayn', 'Yawm ath-thulaathaa\'',
            'Yawm al-arbi\'aa\'', 'Yawm al-kham?s', 'Yawm al-jum\'a', 'Yawm as-sabt'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Aha', 'Ith', 'Thu', 'Arb', 'Kha', 'Jum', 'Sab'],
            dayNamesMin: ['Ah','It','Th','Ar','Kh','Ju','Sa'],
            dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd', // See format options on BaseCalendar.formatDate
            firstDay: 6, // The first day of the week, Sun = 0, Mon = 1, ...
            isRTL: false // True if right-to-left language, false if left-to-right
        }
    },

    /* Determine whether this date is in a leap year.
       @param  year  (CDate) the date to examine or
                     (number) the year to examine
       @return  (boolean) true if this is a leap year, false if not
       @throws  error if an invalid year or a different calendar used */
    leapYear: function(year) {
        var date = this._validate(year, this.minMonth, this.minDay, $.calendars.local.invalidYear);
        return (date.year() * 11 + 14) % 30 < 11;
    },

    /* Determine the week of the year for a date.
       @param  year   (CDate) the date to examine or
                      (number) the year to examine
       @param  month  (number) the month to examine
       @param  day    (number) the day to examine
       @return  (number) the week of the year
       @throws  error if an invalid date or a different calendar used */
    weekOfYear: function(year, month, day) {
        // Find Sunday of this week starting on Sunday
        var checkDate = this.newDate(year, month, day);
        checkDate.add(-checkDate.dayOfWeek(), 'd');
        return Math.floor((checkDate.dayOfYear() - 1) / 7) + 1;
    },

    /* Retrieve the number of days in a year.
       @param  year   (CDate) the date to examine or
                      (number) the year to examine
       @return  (number) the number of days
       @throws  error if an invalid year or a different calendar used */
    daysInYear: function(year) {
        return (this.leapYear(year) ? 355 : 354);
    },

    /* Retrieve the number of days in a month.
       @param  year   (CDate) the date to examine or
                      (number) the year of the month
       @param  month  (number) the month
       @return  (number) the number of days in this month
       @throws  error if an invalid month/year or a different calendar used */
    daysInMonth: function(year, month) {
        var date = this._validate(year, month, this.minDay, $.calendars.local.invalidMonth);
        return this.daysPerMonth[date.month() - 1] +
            (date.month() == 12 && this.leapYear(date.year()) ? 1 : 0);
    },

    /* Determine whether this date is a week day.
       @param  year   (CDate) the date to examine or
                      (number) the year to examine
       @param  month  (number) the month to examine
       @param  day    (number) the day to examine
       @return  (boolean) true if a week day, false if not
       @throws  error if an invalid date or a different calendar used */
    weekDay: function(year, month, day) {
        return this.dayOfWeek(year, month, day) != 5;
    },

    /* Retrieve the Julian date equivalent for this date,
       i.e. days since January 1, 4713 BCE Greenwich noon.
       @param  year   (CDate) the date to convert or
                      (number) the year to convert
       @param  month  (number) the month to convert
       @param  day    (number) the day to convert
       @return  (number) the equivalent Julian date
       @throws  error if an invalid date or a different calendar used */
    toJD: function(year, month, day) {
        var date = this._validate(year, month, day, $.calendars.local.invalidDate);
        year = date.year();
        month = date.month();
        day = date.day();
        year = (year <= 0 ? year + 1 : year);
        return day + Math.ceil(29.5 * (month - 1)) + (year - 1) * 354 +
            Math.floor((3 + (11 * year)) / 30) + this.jdEpoch - 1;
    },

    /* Create a new date from a Julian date.
       @param  jd  (number) the Julian date to convert
       @return  (CDate) the equivalent date */
    fromJD: function(jd) {
        jd = Math.floor(jd) + 0.5;
        var year = Math.floor((30 * (jd - this.jdEpoch) + 10646) / 10631);
        year = (year <= 0 ? year - 1 : year);
        var month = Math.min(12, Math.ceil((jd - 29 - this.toJD(year, 1, 1)) / 29.5) + 1);
        var day = jd - this.toJD(year, month, 1) + 1;
        return this.newDate(year, month, day);
    }
    });

    // Islamic (16 civil) calendar implementation
     $.calendars.calendars.islamic = IslamicCalendar;

     })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score -1):

That's hacking pure and simple and I would not encourage this design.

ADF supports creation of new languages. For example, I can have my ENGLISH_FLORIN language and I can change all ADF text to match my special language.

On top of that, you can use skinning for customizing any ADF component text, including the calendar:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/web.1111/b31973/af_skin.htm#ADFUI10007